# Flutter Desktop alterar título, posição e tamanho da janela principal

Tags: flutter

Atualmente ao executar uma aplicação desktop o tamanho e título da janela vêm pré-definidos, como alterar estas informações?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como exemplo foi utilizado o projeto de teste padrão disponibilizado no git:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
git clone https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando a versão `1.15.3-pre.37` 
Editar o arquivo: `window_configuration.h` na pasta `windows` e alterar conforme o exemplo:

```
const wchar_t *kFlutterWindowTitle = L"Titulo Minha Aplicacao";
const unsigned int kFlutterWindowOriginX = 0; //posição margem esquerda
const unsigned int kFlutterWindowOriginY = 0; //posição top
const unsigned int kFlutterWindowWidth = 1200; //Largura
const unsigned int kFlutterWindowHeight = 768; //Altura
```

-------EDIT---------

Utilizando a versão `1.19.0-2.0.pre.73` já é possível definir dentro da aplicação:

```
import 'package:window_size/window_size.dart';`


WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
setWindowTitle('Meu app');
const frame = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 1200, 768);
setWindowFrame(frame);
runApp(MyApp());
```

Comment: Eu consigo acessar essas constantes em _runtime_? Ou a aplicação vai obedecer só o que foi setado nesse arquivo? ~~ Quero utilizar o desktop, mas me parece bem instável ainda e sem muitas funções

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro acredito que não, ainda não tive essa necessidade de modificar em tempo de execução, como você falou ainda está bem instável mas já consigo utilizar bastante coisa, `mobx`, `get_it`, etc.